# How to take webpage screenshots with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: screenshot, wkhtmltopdf

I can create PDF file with wkhtmltopdf in linux Ubuntu: "wkhtmltopdf www.stackoverflow.com file.pdf"
How to take webpage screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list) as suggested by [Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438295/how-to-take-webpage-screenshots-with-wkhtmltopdf/5465936#5465936). You can go to the first URL and download the file suitable for your architecture (or its source code). Usage is simple:

```
./wkhtmltoimage-i386 http://www.google.com google.png
```

Answer (score 2):

wkhtmltoimage - this also uses the webkit render engine for excellent results and is available as standalone binary with no install problems anticipated, just trial and error to get the results you need.